# Update collection in file

Tags: c#

I wanted to know how after the removal of the record of List, I can update the file collection

```
private ObservableCollection<ProfileModel> _profileItems = null;
public ObservableCollection<ProfileModel> ProfileItems
```

ModelView:

```
private void ProfileModel_DeleteItemEvent(ProfileModel profileModel)
{
    ProfileItems.Remove(profileModel);

    if (!ProfileItems.Any())
    {
        ShowLoginForm = true;
        ShowProfileItems = false;
    }
    //here wants to insert code
}
```

Menager:

```
private void SaveProfile()   
{
    if (ProfileItems == null) ProfileItems = new List<ProfileModel>();
    if(!ProfileItems.Contains(CurrentUser)) ProfileItems.Add(CurrentUser);

    var list = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ProfileItems);
    FileManagerInstance.WriteTextToFile(FileManager.FileType.ProfileList, list);
}

public async Task<bool> SetProfileList()
{
    var content = await FileManagerInstance.ReadFile(FileManager.FileType.ProfileList);

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
    {
        ProfileItems = new List<ProfileModel>();
        return false;
    }
    try 
    {
        ProfileItems = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProfileModel>>(content);
    } 
    catch(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException ex)
    {
        _log.MessageInDebug("Result content is bad!");

        if (Debugger.IsAttached) 
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    return ProfileItems != null && ProfileItems.Any();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener for your observable collection, like so:

```
   ObservableCollection<ProfileModel> myObservable = new ObservableCollection<ProfileModel>();
            myObservable.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
                {
                    // do stuff
                }
            };
```

Comment: You can a hint me more?

Comment: thats literally how you create the event for your observable collection. use it where you define this   'public ObservableCollection<ProfileModel> ProfileItems'. In the 'do stuff' area you put your code you want to run whenever an item is removed from your ProfileModel collection